# Scratch execution windows blurred & blinking: is video driver faulty?

Tags: driver, mit-scratch

I installed Lubuntu 19.04 on old Inspiron 6400 computer (GeForce 7300 laptop edition) to teach Scratch to my son through web scratch editor. Every time I open web editor for a new project through firefox, right zone with the cat is blurred and blinks like if video driver was badly configured.

Here is screenshot: [image]

At the beginning I used to have this for the whole Ubuntu system, any application.
Using now Lubuntu, everything seems correct but that srcatch window.

Is it still a video driver issue ? Or is the problem on Scratch application side ?

**Edit:**
So I revert back to Lubuntu 16.04 to better support GeForce 7300, and eveything gets corrected. Then I upgraded firefox through: `sudo apt install firefox`. This performed the following:

```
Start-Date: 2020-03-28  12:06:21
Commandline: apt install firefox
Requested-By: me (1001)
Install: libatomic1:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12, automatic)
Upgrade: cpp-5:i386 (5.3.1-14ubuntu2, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12), libquadmath0:i386 (5.3.1-14ubuntu2, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12), gcc-5-base:i386 (5.3.1-14ubuntu2, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12), libgomp1:i386 (5.3.1-14ubuntu2, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12), firefox:i386 (45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1, 74.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libstdc++6:i386 (5.3.1-14ubuntu2, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)
```

And problem is back again. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try https://get.webgl.org/ - do you see the spinning cube? If not, then the problem is indeed on your computer, and you may find help with that at https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that only some part of the graphics is faulty. Most likely, this is processing and web error. I would recommend checking if you have Adobe Flash and/or Chrome on your computer.
Hopefully this helps.